# re.compile("[" ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-7: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, regex

I want to run this code so as to get every happy emoji in my tweets. But I am getting error. I am using google colab. I am doing this.

```py
emoji_pattern_happy = re.compile("["
                           u"\U0001F600"
                           u"\U0001F617" # emoticons
                           u"\U0001F642"
                           u"\U0001F60A" 
                           u"\U0001F60D"
                           u"\U0001236A"
                           u"\U0001F61A"
                           u"\U0001F63A"
                           u"\U0001F63B"
                           u"\U0001F61B"
                           u"\U0001F60E"
                           u"\U0001F60C"
                           u"\U0001F642"
                           u"\U0001F923"
                           u"\U0001F494"
                           u"\U00012764"
                           u"\U0001F499"
                           u"\U0001F49C"
                           u"\U0001F9OE"
                           u"\U0001F970"
                           u"\U0001F64C"
                           u"\U0001F4AF"
                           u"\U0001F91D"
                           u"\U0001F49F"
                           u"\U0002763"
                           u"\U0001F913"
                           u"\U0001F415"
                           u"\U0001F4AB"
                           u"\U0001F91F"
                           u"\U0001F44D"
                           u"\U0001F44F"
                           u"\U0001F924"
                           u"\U0001F496"
                           u"\U0001F497"
                           u"\U0001F493"
                           u"\U0001F49B"
                           u"\U0001F49A"
                           u"\U0001F920"
                           u"\U000F9E1"
                           u"\U0001F48B" 
                           u"\U0001F48C" 
                           u"\U0001F498" 
                           u"\U0001F49D"
                           u"\U0001F973"
                           u"\U0001F917"
                           u"\U0001F638"
                           u"\U0001F642" 
                           "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide an example showing how you are retrieving and parsing your tweets? Include the full traceback with your post.

Comment: The `\U` escape must be followed by exactly eight hex characters.

Comment: yes it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You left a `1` out of `u"\U0002763"` and `u"\U000F9E1"`; presumably you meant `u"\U00012763"` (not sure on that) and `u"\U0001F9E1"` (seems likely). `\U` escapes require precisely eight hex digits. Luckily, the `SyntaxError` prevented you from accidentally searching for some random unrelated character.